# Using Firebase for iOS and Android apps

Tags: android, ios, swift, firebase, kotlin

I'm working on a personal project by developping two native apps, one for iOS (Swift) and the other one for Android (Kotlin). 
Both apps are for money management and banking.

My question is about firebase, should I create 2 different projects on Firebase and connect each one of my apps to one project at a time, or one Firebase-project can do the job for both apps ?

Any explanations are appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: AFAIK, A single Firebase project, like a cloud back-end service, can be shared with iOS, Android and Web.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42731422/same-firebase-instance-for-ios-and-android-app, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41107699/using-same-firebase-app-with-web-and-mobile-app, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46185098/how-can-i-add-an-android-app-to-an-existing-firebase-project-that-is-already-in

Comment: It's possible to have multiple apps in different technologies within a single Firebase project. Just keep in mind that all apps within a project use the same databases, the same list of users, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should create a single project with two applications, one for iOs and one for Android. There is **no** need to create two projects, one for each platfom.

If you also intend in the future to create a web app, you'll only have to create a new (web) project and that's it!

Answer (score 2):

In Firebase, every projects you created, you can add as many applications as you want.
An example below:
[image: Two Apps in the same project]

**Two Apps in the same project**

You are given a choice of iOS, Android, UNITY,and Web App to add

Answer (score 2):

[Please see the Google firebase doc you can find the setup for both platforms](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/)

> You dont need to create seprate project you can manage both in one project.