# Flutter mobile app and VueJS web app using the same Firebase back-end

Tags: firebase, flutter, vue.js

Is it possible to have a VueJS web application and a Flutter mobile application that communicate with each other through chat using the same Firebase backend?

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem, you should just add a web and mobile app to your Firebase project.

Answer (score 1):

A single Firebase project can be used as the back-end for many (iOS, Web and Android) apps. All these apps will be talking to the same back-end services.

So if you create two web applications on a single Firebase project, those apps will be using the same database, the same list of users, the same stored files, etc. If you then add an iOS or Android app, that will also be accessing the same users/database/files.

(from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41108143/13646430)